# Add data to a table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add data to table by taking input from a form. I am storing the json data in an array but the second time data is not getting appended cause of this only one data is shown in the table. I just want to know how to append json data without resetting the value of the variable

My js file

getting data from forms

```
 const [rows,setRows]=useState([])
  const data=[];
  function createData(medicationname,strength,s_unit,prep,route,dose,d_unit,directionvalue,freq,durationvalue,quantityvalue,instructions) {
    return {medicationname,strength,s_unit,prep,route,dose,d_unit,directionvalue,freq,durationvalue,quantityvalue,instructions};
  }
  const handledialogsubmit=useCallback(async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {medicationname,strength,s_unit,prep,route,dose,d_unit,directionvalue,freq,durationvalue,quantityvalue,instructions}=event.target.elements

  const a=createData(medicationname.value,strength.value,s_unit.value,prep.value,route.value,dose.value,d_unit.value,directionvalue.value,freq.value,durationvalue.value,quantityvalue.value,instructions.value)
   data.push(a)

  setRows(data)
  console.log(rows,data)  

  setOpenPopup(false)

  });
```

Table function

```
const showTable=()=>{
    const TableRow=(rows)=>{
      const{medicationname,strength,directionvalue,durationvalue,quantityvalue}=rows;
      return (
        <>
          <tr>
          <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {medicationname}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {strength}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {directionvalue}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {durationvalue}
          </span>
        </td>        <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {quantityvalue}
          </span>
        </td>        <td>
          <span className="fw-normal">
            {buttons}
          </span>
        </td>
          </tr>

  
  
  
        </>
    
      )

    }
    return(

      <Table hover className="user-table align-items-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th className="border-bottom">Medication Name</th>
          <th className="border-bottom">Strength</th>
          <th className="border-bottom">Direction</th>
          <th className="border-bottom">Duration</th>
          <th className="border-bottom">Quantity</th>
          <th className="border-bottom">Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map(t => <TableRow key={`data-${t.medicationname}`} {...t} />)}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Where is the forma and code that adds a row? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: {rows.map(t => <TableRow key={`data-${t.medicationname}`} {...t} />)}

Comment: i have edit my question can you check now

Comment: What is calling `createData`? Please try to make a codesandbox